Read all data as text from SSIS Excel data source
I am using an Excel data source in SSIS with the connection string: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\MyFolder\MyData.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=NO;IMEX=1";
In column L I have the values:
16,100 for row 11
17,310 for row 23
16,100 for row 30

All the other columns are NULL. When I preview the data in the Excel connection manager, it shows data as:
16100
17310
16110

it means that the driver removes the comma (,), I do not want it to do that. All I want is to treat all the data as text even if the values are numeric. I have ImportMixedTypes=Text in all keys in Windows registry.
I tried IMEX=1 in Excel connection string, TypeGuessRows = 0 and ImportMixedTypes=Text in Windows registry.
All I want is to treat all the data as text even if the values are numeric.

Is the file an actual Excel file or a comma delimited/.CSV file?  If CSV (even though it opens in Excel) you can use a text file connection manager to connect.
